# filebeat - permission denied errors on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04, filebeat

I am facing the following error while running filebeat

`$ filebeat test config`

```
2019-03-20 01:57:12.112399037 +0000 UTC m=+0.016941991 write error: failed to open new file: open /var/log/filebeat/filebeat: permission denied
2019-03-20 01:57:12.112659642 +0000 UTC m=+0.017202599 write error: failed to open new file: open /var/log/filebeat/filebeat: permission denied
Exiting: Beat meta file failed to open: open /var/lib/filebeat/meta.json: permission denied
```

Does anyone know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo filebeat test config
```

Above command should work, provided the owner of the file is root.